# Retrieve object from Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm developing a simple iOS application. It's a simple quiz app. I'm using Parse to store my questions, answers etc. I've read all the documentation and cannot find why this code to retrieve an object is not working.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Test_Questions")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("cJzv2JdMej", block: {
    (questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    let thisQuestion = questionObject["question"] as! String
    //Error here: AnyObject is not convertible to String

})
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Console Output:

Optional(What statement must come before an else statement?)

Comment: try printing questionObject and error (println("Object: \(questionObject) - Error: \(error)"))

Answer (score 1):

You should try this instead:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Test_Questions")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("cJzv2JdMej", block: {
(questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println(questionObject)
        //if there's info in the console you know the object was retrieved
        let thisQuestion = questionObject["question"] as? String

    } else {
        println("Error occurred retrieving object")
    }
})
```

If that doesn't work you can also try `let thisQuestion = questionObject.valueForKey("question")`. Also make sure that Parse is actually returning an object by adding a print statement such as `println(questionObject)` after it has been retrieved so that you know Parse is returning an object.

Comment: You should add the else statement in case error != nil printing the error returned

Comment: You're right I added the check for error they didn't originally have but I was being lazy by not adding the else check, thanks.

Comment: 1 more thing, it should be: println("Error occurred retrieving object, error: \(error)")

Comment: Well that's just symantics and debugging preferences at that point, but yes that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok so now I have a UI Label like so: **@IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!** how do I append this to output the question using that? I still get the AnyObject String error.

Comment: You would do that by `question.text = thisQuestion`. What is in your console if you print out `println(thisQuestion)`?

Comment: When I use println I get the output I am looking for in the console, however when I try to say question.text = thisQuestion I get **Cannot assign a value of type AnyObject? to a value of type String?** Any one?

Comment: What if you try `if let thisQuestion : String = questionObject["question"] as? String { question.text = thisQuestion }`

Comment: **String? is not convertible to String**

Comment: Try it with a !. Sorry I'm not at my mac right now so hard for me to test things out. Are you sure that your question field in parse is actually stored as a string? It shouldn't be this difficult to get the value from a `PFObject`

Comment: @pbush25 I know tell me about it! I recently upgraded to Xcode 6.4 maybe that has something to do with it. I've tried it with an ! as well. No luck! Yes question field in Parse in stored as a String type too.

Comment: Can you update your original question with a screenshot of your console when it prints out the question object please?

Comment: With an ! the error is **AnyObject? is not convertible to String**

Comment: Added. **Optional(What statement must come before an else statement?)**

Comment: So it just displays `optional()`? That means that it's not actually working and something is nil

Comment: Well no it is working. It is outputting correctly in the console. The optional value was because I had [let thisQuestion: AnyObject? = questionObject!.valueForKey("question")] AnyObject was optional. I've now changed the ? to ! and it outputs the String in Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Test_Questions")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("cJzv2JdMej", block: {
        (questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let thisQuestion: AnyObject! = questionObject!.valueForKey("question")

        self.question.text = thisQuestion as? String

        })
```